# Cannot choose from an empty sequence Locust Error

Tags: python, locust

I am attempting to run a Locust file and am repeatedly facing the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 280, in run
    self.schedule_task(self.get_next_task())
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 408, in get_next_task
    return random.choice(self.user.tasks)
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 260, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

My locust file looks like this:

```
import base64

from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task
from random import randint, choice


class WebTasks(TaskSet):

    @task
    def load(self):
        base64string = base64.encodebytes(('%s:%s' % ('user', 'password')).encode()).decode().replace('\n', '')

        catalogue = self.client.get("/catalogue").json()
        category_item = choice(catalogue)
        item_id = category_item["id"]

        self.client.get("/")
        self.client.get("/login", headers={"Authorization":"Basic %s" % base64string})
        self.client.get("/category.html")
        self.client.get("/detail.html?id={}".format(item_id))
        self.client.delete("/cart")
        self.client.post("/cart", json={"id": item_id, "quantity": 1})
        self.client.get("/basket.html")
        self.client.post("/orders")

class Web(HttpUser):
    task_set = WebTasks
    min_wait = 0
    max_wait = 0
```

I believe the issue normally arises from not having any tasks defined, but I do have a task defined here so I am not sure why I would be getting this error. I am running on Python 3.6.8 and Locust 1.0.2 on Mac OS.

Comment: As an aside, are you not using a dedicated Conda environment?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is for one of these lines:

```
category_item = choice(catalogue)
# or
item_id = choice(self.client.get("/catalogue").json())["id"]
```

So the call to `catalogue = self.client.get("/catalogue").json()` returned an empty list/iterable. Both the "catalogue get" are the same call.

---

This section doesn't make sense:

```
catalogue = self.client.get("/catalogue").json()  # 1A
print(catalogue)
category_item = choice(catalogue)                 # 1B
item_id = category_item["id"]

item_id = choice(self.client.get("/catalogue").json())["id"]  #2
```

You get the catalogue in '1A' and then make a random choice in '1B', which is then ignored/unused, and then you get *the same catalogue again* and make a random choice in '#2', but this time you select the item's `"id"`. Just skip to the 2nd one.

---

And you've not created `task_set` correctly:

```
class Web(HttpUser):
    task_set = WebTasks  # is just a reference to the WebTasks class
```

Should be:

```
class Web(HttpUser):
    task_set = WebTasks()  # to *create an object* of the WebTasks class
```

Comment: I apologize, was just trying to see if somehow the 2 methods to get the catalogue would produce different results, there should only be 1 of those implementations. Problem is, even without accessing the catalogue (if I comment it out) I still get the error

Comment: Did you fix the `task_set = WebTasks` vs `task_set = WebTasks()` ?

Comment: In any case, even in the edited function with just one call to get-catalogue, it seems it's returning an empty collection. So `choice` is throwing an error because it can't randomly select from an empty collection, as mentioned in my answer. What is the output of `print(catalogue)` which you had before? Provide a sample if the whole thing is too big.

Comment: As I said, when I comment out all of the lines that access the catalogue (and consequently item_id) I still get the error. I found that if I move the task into the Web class things work, no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

There have been some changes in Locust 1.0, so try replacing

```
task_set = WebTasks
```

with

```
tasks = [WebTasks]
```

Or do away with the TaskSet entirely and place your @task declarations directly on the User. For more info, see https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/changelog.html#changelog-1-0

The error message is bad though, I thought we had improved that...